# Errors when access to SQLITE database from PHP (but it works from command line ...)

Tags: php, sqlite

I've this simple PHP code in which I connect a SQLITE data base ...

```
<?php
   ini_set('display_errors', 1);

   echo 'Current script owner: ' . get_current_user();

   # Set access to data base...
   $db = new SQLite3('/var/www/html/OpenProntoSoccorso/Test/OpenProntoSoccorso.sqlite');

   echo ".... Connessione db OK! ...";
?>
```

when I try to execute from browser I've this error ...

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Unable to open database: unable to open database file' in /var/www/html/OpenProntoSoccorso/Test/testSpatialite.php:6 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/OpenProntoSoccorso/Test/testSpatialite.php(6): SQLite3->__construct('/var/www/html/O...') #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/OpenProntoSoccorso/Test/testSpatialite.php on line 6
```

but when I try to execute form command line all work fine

```
root@osboxes:/var/www/html/OpenProntoSoccorso/Test# ls -l
total 336536
-rwxr-x--- 1 root    root    330037248 Aug 17 14:20 OpenProntoSoccorso.sqlite
-rw-rw-r-- 1 osboxes osboxes       133 Aug 17 13:51 testSpatialite.php
root@osboxes:/var/www/html/OpenProntoSoccorso/Test# php testSpatialite.php 
.... Connessione db OK! ...root@osboxes:/var/www/html/OpenProntoSoccorso/Test#
```

I've tried to change owner and/or group but nothing change ...

Suggestions?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Your permissions are wrong. Right now only root can access that database. You PHP does not (and should not) run as root on your web server. But when you are from the command line, you are logged on as root so when you execute the PHP code, it have root privileges

Comment: I've the same behavior if I try to change OpenProntoSoccorso.sqlite owner and group to "osboxes"  ....

Comment: Probably because your web server does not run as osboxes but as some other unprevileged user

Comment: How may I check this? I'm on Ubuntu 15.10 ..

Comment: the quick and dirty way -> http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-current-user.php

Comment: I've tried to change the file owner to "osboxes" and add at my code `echo 'Current script owner: ' . get_current_user();` (see above ....), and it tells me "osboxes" as current user both from browser and from command line ....

Comment: Seems like it return the owner of the file. You want owner of the process. try this `$processUser = posix_getpwuid(posix_geteuid()); echo $processUser['name'];` (it's the first comment on the link I sent you)

Comment: Ok I solved. If you want, try to convert your comments in an aswer, so I can vote it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your permissions are wrong. Right now only root can access that database. You PHP does not (and should not) run as root on your web server. But when you are running it from the command line, you are logged on as root so when you execute the PHP code, it have root privileges.

To fix it, you will need to change the file permissions. for that, you can use [`chown`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/chown). To know to which user you must transfer the ownership to, you can use this quick and dirty snippet

```
$processUser = posix_getpwuid(posix_geteuid());
echo $processUser['name'];
```